# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: [0, 33, 385, Will];

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception, apache-spark-sql

I am building a basic sparkSQL program with the following code but getting the
*Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: [0, 33, 385, Will];*
at the runtime.

```
    package com.LearningSpark.app2

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.log4j._

object SparkSQLDataset {

  case class Person(id: Int, name: String, age: Int, friends: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("SparkSQL")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val schemaPeople = spark.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv("C:/fakefriends.csv")
      .as[Person]
    
    schemaPeople.printSchema()
    
    schemaPeople.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("people")
    
    val teenagers = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM global_temp.people WHERE age >=13 and age <= 19")
    
    val results = teenagers.collect()
    
    results.foreach(println)
    
    spark.stop()

  }

}
```

Below the exception I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: [0, 33, 385, Will];
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$checkAnalysis$1$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$checkAnalysis$1$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$2(TreeNode.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChild$2(TreeNode.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$4(TreeNode.scala:427)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$mapExpressions$1(QueryPlan.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$mapExpressions$4(QueryPlan.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis$(CheckAnalysis.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.resolveAndBind(ExpressionEncoder.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.resolvedEnc$lzycompute(Dataset.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$resolvedEnc(Dataset.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.as(Dataset.scala:475)
    at com.LearningSpark.app2.SparkSQLDataset$.main(SparkSQLDataset.scala:25)
    at com.LearningSpark.app2.SparkSQLDataset.main(SparkSQLDataset.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code

```
   val schemaPeople = spark.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv("C:/fakefriends.csv")
```

it loads a CSV file (fakefriends.csv) and assumes the first line of the file contains the columns names.
However, the error says `given input columns: [0, 33, 385, Will];` which is, the column names don't look at all like column names, and it's probably because the CSV file does not actually have a header. Have a look at fakefriends.csv and look at the first line, it's likely `0,33,385,Will` when it should have been `id, age friends,name`, so it's reading the first line of data as column names. Also note that the order is different from how you defined it in `Person`.
Solution is to either add the line containing the column names in the csv file, or supply the schema to `spark.read` :

```
   # your spark may need to be at least 2.4.5 for this to work
    val schemaPeople = spark.read.format("csv").
      .option("header", "false")
      # since the schema is provided, we don't need inferSchema
      .schema("id int ,age int, friends int, name string")
      .load("C:/fakefriends.csv")
```

Comment: The CSV file that I was using didn't have any header. I added the header in the file and it worked. Thank You Roberto.